# React line chart using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I implement dynamic chart in React using Chart.js. I have data coming from API every 10min and I want to populate chart with that data. Here is code for getting data

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/data')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({chartData: [...this.state.chartData, json[0]]}));
```

Here is code for chart data

```
const data = {
          labels: this.props.data.date
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Data1',
              data: this.props.data.entry
            }
```

Passing props to Chart component

```
<Chart data={this.props.chartData} />
```

Line chart in component

```
<Line data={data}  />
```

Comment: First You need to make the API call every ten minutes. Is your server maintaining some connection  with your client and pushing data to client ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [React wrapper around ChartJS](https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs) available from the React team. It supports line charts. This may be simpler than building your own, or at least use it for inspiration.